# Delay reading a file?

Tags: c, linux, polling

The input file lines below as well is formatted as "swi delay interval"
where interval is an integer in milliseconds. Each time swi encounters such a line, the
switch delays reading (and processing) the remaining part of the input file for the specified
time duration. During this period, the switch should continue monitoring and processing
keyboard commands and packets received from the attached devices. This features simulates
delays in receiving packets from hosts served by the switch.

I thought about using wait() but soon realized that's not how you go about delaying. How can I go about doing this? below code is how I'm reading from the traffic file right now. I am using poll() to monitor other file descriptors.

```
       /*Read the traffic file */
            while((ch = fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)){
                    if(line[0] == '#' || line[0] == ' ' || line[0] == '\n' || (!strstr(line, switchI))){
                            continue;
                    }
                    if(line[4] == 'd'){

                            strcpy(newline, line);
                            tempp = strtok(newline, " ");
                            tempp = strtok(NULL, " ");
                            strcpy(delay, tempp);
                            tempp = strtok(NULL, " ");
                            interval = atoi(tempp);
                            //printf("%s\n", line);
                            //printf("%s, %d\n", delay, interval);
```

---

```
 sw1 delay 2000
 sw1  100  101
 sw1  100  102
 sw1  100  700
 sw1 delay 2000
#
 sw2 delay 2000
 sw2  500  501
 sw2  500  502
 sw2  500  700
 sw2 delay 2000
 #  
  sw3 delay 2000
  sw3  200  201
  sw3  200  202
  sw3  200  700
```

Comment: From my point of view, there is too little information to answer you correctly. If you want to delay, well, wait is a way, but it seem to me that you rather want a non-blocking way. So could you provide more detail please ? Also, when you say "swi", do i only go from 1 to 9 ? Or it could be more, like "sw11" ?

Comment: @Tom's swi only goes up 7 and yes I would rather use a non-blocking way.

Comment: Are you using thread ? Like "one thread for each descriptor file" ?

Comment: @Tom's providing more code would be helpful. I will be monitoring at most 6 fds.I was wondering if I have to poll for the traffic file?

Comment: @Tom's I'm not using threads, using poll()

Comment: Well, I am a little rusty, but what you could do is "simply" having a structure associating a "file" with a "delay". When you "poll", you go througth the array : if "delay" is 0, you add the file descriptor to the polling, if delay is not 0, you do not add the file and you retain in memory the minimum delay of all. Then you poll only the file descriptor without delay with a timer equal to the minimum delay. if poll do a timeout, go back to step one (do not forget to update delay). There should have detail left to fix, but I think it could work

Comment: @Tom's I'm not quite sure I follow. Will I be able to delay for the specified amount of time in the traffic file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184077/discussion-between-toms-and-pennyboy).

Comment: Check select() system call and you can add delay there and perhaps make blocking and non blocking also.

Comment: You could read the traffic file first, parsing each line into a structure of some sort.  It might even make sense to use an array or linked list per switch, if a delay on one switch should not affect the operation of the other switches. Because you have told us **nothing** about how you receive and forward the packets, it is impossible to help you further.